# NSMutableArray in Custom cell implementation issue

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray

So i had this code on my SpecialOfferCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AFImagePager.h"
@interface SpecialOfferCell : UITableViewCell<AFImagePagerDataSource,AFImagePagerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *arrayImages;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger offer_id;
-(void)loadImages;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet AFImagePager *imageIcons;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *descLabel;

@end
```

and this is the implementation file

```
#import "SpecialOfferCell.h"

@implementation SpecialOfferCell
@synthesize arrayImages;
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {

}
return self;
}

 - (void)awakeFromNib
 {
// Initialization code
self.imageIcons.delegate=self;
self.imageIcons.dataSource=self;


}


 -(NSArray*)getArrayImages{
 return  [NSArray arrayWithArray:arrayImages];
 }
#pragma mark - AFImagePager DataSource
- (NSArray *) arrayWithImageUrlStrings
{
 return [self getArrayImages];
}

- (UIViewContentMode) contentModeForImage:(NSUInteger)image
{
  return UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
 }
- (UIImage *) placeHolderImageForImagePager{
  return [UIImage imageNamed:@"stub_dashboard"];
}
 -(void)loadImages{
NSLog(@"offer id :%d",self.offer_id);
NSLog(@"arrayImages:%d",arrayImages.count);
@try {
    if (arrayImages.count==0) {
        NSError* error;
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[appConfig URL_GET_OFFER_GALLERY]]];

        NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"hotel_id\":\"%@\",\"key\":\"%@\",\"offer_id\":%ld}",@"ayodya",[appConfig API_KEY],(long)_offer_id];
        NSLog(@"%@",post);
        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];  // multipart/form-data
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];


        NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
        //NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        //NSLog(@"%@",returnString);
        NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        arrayImages=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        NSMutableArray *arrayImagesTemp=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        arrayImagesTemp=[json objectForKey:@"galeries"];
        for (int i=0; i<arrayImagesTemp.count; i++) {
            NSDictionary * Object=[[NSDictionary alloc]init];
            Object=[arrayImagesTemp objectAtIndex:i];
            [arrayImages addObject:[Object objectForKey:@"image"]];
        }
        [self.imageIcons reloadData];

    }

}
@catch (NSException *exception) {

}
}

@end
```

So when i called this custom cell in the UITableViewController the array image using array that has been used before, so when initizialize new cell, the array not refreshed. Why is that? is it because the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier?

Data source:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
 NSDictionary * Object=[[NSDictionary alloc]init];
 Object=[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SpecialOfferCell";
 SpecialOfferCell *cell = (SpecialOfferCell *)[tableView
                                       dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

 cell.titleLabel.text=[Object objectForKey:@"offer_title"];
 [cell setOffer_id:[[Object objectForKey:@"offer_id"]integerValue]];

 [cell performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadImages) withObject:nil];

 return cell;
 }
```

So what I am going to achieve here is, when the cell have loaded the images, it wont load again.
[image: TableView]

Comment: Hi, can you please paste your table view datasource implementation code also?

Answer (score 0):

In your SpecialOfferCell you need to implement `prepareForReuse` here you can reset any data such as the image array

Comment: but reseting data will cause the method loadImages called over and over again. in my case after the third cell. What is the best approach for this? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this part of code is useless:

```
if (cell == nil)
{
     cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

You should create new cell instead of dequeuing it again.

I don't know what you really want to achieve. There are two options:

1. In `prepareForReuse` you can remove images to load them again with `loadImages`.
2. You don't remove images - in this case, when cell is reused, it has images previously loaded, so basically random.

But if you need to load images from server only once, you can create dictionary and each time in `loadImages` check if your images has already been loaded and get them from your dictionary. Am I understanding it right?

Comment: Every part of the cells contain different images so here I used AFImagePager, So I passed the id of each offer_id to SpecialOfferCell.m to loadImages based on it's offer_id. Solution 1, I don't intend to remove the images, all I want is when all of the images loaded to each cell, it won't load the images again. Solution 2, the third cell will contain images from the first cell.

Comment: So, what you need to do is keep reference to your array of images in some dictionary where key is your offer name or other unique identifier (eg. indexPath) and in 'loadImages' you try to load them from dictionary and load them form server when dictionary[yourKey] is null. Am I understanding your problem correctly?